# All Products disappeared from the frontend after installing Solr for Magento EE1.12

Tags: magento, solr

I have been tasked with installing Solr for a Magento site running EE1.12.  I following the tutorials and read up on all the documentation on the Magento site.  I have Java 1.6 installed and then downloaded Solr to the /root/etc folder.  I was then able to configure Solr in the backend and when I tested the connection it succeded.  So I then proceeded to reindex my catalog search, ensured all my indexes were up to date.  Navigated back to the front end and now ALL the products are gone.  Even when you navigate to them through the menu bar they aren't there.

1) I immediately went back, ensured they were set to visible, set to searchable, and listed in at least one category.  So it is not a backend property issue with the products themselves.

At this point I'm at a loss, I have been scouring the internet for a similar issue or a possible how to fix it and can't find anything so far.

Thanks for any insights you can provide!

Comment: Did you attempt to install SOLR 4.x?  We had to revert to 3.6 because there were some compatibility issues with 1.12..  Also, did you reindex all -- and then clear cache?  Next thing to check is to go to your back end ie `http://yoursite.com:8080/solr/admin` and search for the string `*:*` to see if SOLR is updating indexes?

Comment: I actually installed Solr 3.5 so I must have been following an older guide.  I did reindex all, twice, and clear every bit of cache just to be sure.  I tried accessing  the /solr/admin but it just tossed an error.

Comment: Well that's important ..  The SOLR is breaking.  No wonder you don't see anything in Magento.  Did you test SOLR by itself before trying to connect Magento to it?

Comment: No I didn't test it alone, this was just kinda of thrust on me, never worked with it before, and that wasn't part of the tutorial I was given. I get 404 not found error when I try the solr/admin link.

Comment: Disconnect it from Magento, change the back end to mysql full text, and then reinstall SOLR and get it working correctly before attempting to connect Magento.  My guess is you probably may not have copied the Magento config files etc ..  Start from scratch, get it working **THEN** connect Magento.

Comment: It turns out that Jetty was never started, once that was in place then it seemed to work.  I also needed to copy the Apache/Solr/conf files to /usr/share/solr/conf and then restarted Jetty.  Once the data was re-indexed and cache was flushed (for the 100th time) everything worked.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem after installing Solr.

Version was 3.6.2. When fulltext search was selected in admin (system/configuration/catalog) everything was working fine. After a switch to Solr, all products on category pages went missing. The solution was to:

- copy files from magento solr config (lib/Apache/Solr/conf) to solr config (INSTALL_DIR/example/solr/conf).
- It is important for the version to be 3.6 because I tried it with the newest and there are some conflicts with configuration files (after copying them).
- Start the jetty/tomcat (whatever you are using for solr)
- When it is up, go and reindex all (`php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall`) so that magento can fill the solr with data.

That should be it.